# How to run sikuli? Where is path?

Tags: java

I installed sikuli from repositories.

Now, when I run sikuli-ide from terminal it says: command not found.
Where is the path.
There is no icon to run it from Show Application.

Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please specify your Ubuntu version and full name of the package. Try `sikulix` command instead (know this from [package contents](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/sikulix/filelist)).

Comment: Also check https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1793852 - it does not start on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.